# How to remove a string from a text file in shell command?

Tags: shell, unix, ubuntu, cygwin, putty

I have a non.txt file and want to write a shell script to remove a string from the entire file. File has the following data :-

```
24321,247,654,"^A","91350","JEFFR2",21714,,1,243,654,"^A","91350","JEFFR2",21714,,1,654,0,"P","N","1140828","CA",,,,,"06037","C016","14","7",0,"21714 JEFFERS LN","","SANTA CLARITA","CA","913503917","","","","20140828"
```

And from the above set of data i want to remove "^A".

Please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: Please include your coding attempt. (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: So what is the rule for removal and what is your desired output? Do you just want to remove that particular string, or is it always the 4th field? What about the commas surrounding the string? What have you tried already?

Comment: Also please review your choice of tags - you should probably remove [tag:ubuntu], [tag:cygwin] and [tag:putty] unless you have a specific reason to include them (which you should explain).

Comment: @TomFenech i just want to remove this string from the file and it is not occurring at any particular position. It is coming at any position.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed -i 's/"^A"//g' non.txt
```